# Making Direct Request with v2 chainlink specs

Tags: chainlink

##### Background of Problem

I have used v1 (JSON initiators) with external adapters and also the core chainlink jobs (like httpget for instance) with Chainlink. Recently, it seems that v2 jobs are being pushed, and those look really exciting and powerful. They utilize a TOML file instead of JSON. My team and I were looking at writing our own custom external adapter for a [Direct Request](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/types/direct-request). I had a few questions, though once I was going through the docs.

##### Areas of Confusion

In docs they have this smart contract snippet given, which is very similar to any chainlink flow in a smart contract

```
contract MyClient is ChainlinkClient {
function doRequest() public {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(specId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    req.add("fetchURL", "https://datafeed.xyz/eth");
    req.add("jsonPath", "data,result");
}

function fulfill(bytes32 requestID, uint256 answer) public {
    // ...
}
}
```

Then in their pipeline for the job, we see in the type="ethdecodeabi" snippet

```
decode_log  [type="ethabidecodelog"
         data="$(jobRun.logData)"
         topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"
         abi="SomeContractEvent(bytes32 requestID, bytes cborPayload)"]

decode_cbor [type="cborparse"
         data="$(decode_log.cborPayload)"]
```

So, when reading in "ethabidecodelog" it states that the abi must be a canonical event, named same as in Solidity...but when looking at contract (and in past) you never had a contract that explicitly called bytes parameter. In fact, only event triggered with sendChainlinkRequest function (which I'm guessing was omitted???) is ChainlinkRequested(bytes32). So, do we need to make a new event? that brings up other question, though, which is that buildChainlinkRequest encodes added parameters already into CBOR payload inside the mutable buffer (I think, iirc... the version 0.8 Chainlink.sol and Chainlinkclient.sol inherit from lots of interfaces/contracts). If that is the case, do we need our event we create to take in bytes buf from the buffer struct?

Once the event is called correctly, and the CBOR payload is passed, the rest of the script (bar one small detail I'll mention in a second) makes sense.

So, tl;dr,

1. Do you need to call sendChainlinkRequest function in this flow (returns requestId), or do you need an custom event which takes in the CBOR Payload and makes a valid requestID (I think in docs this is make by a keccak256(abi.encode(...)), so you could make this before calling sendChainlinkRequest if needed I think)
2. If you don't need a custom event, then what is the name of the default event under the hood being called that I can put into my abi for type="ethabidecodelog"

lastly, in docs, I also don't know where encode_mwr variable is declared, but it is used as value with data key in data attribute of encode_tx

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

What makes the v2 job specs so powerful is that they give more customizability. So to answer your questions:

1. No, you do not *need* a custom event, but you can make one if you want (as long as you specify the proper event name in the `abi` key-value pair. You can also use the event used in v1 jobs as long you specify that specific event in the job specs. The specific event you need in that case is `OracleRequest()` as [seen in the migration docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/migration-v1-v2/).
2. Since the job v2 specs are optimized for customizability there is no "default" event, it is up to you as the node operator to decide what event to listen out for. Again, if you want to use the event that is triggered with `sendChainlinkRequestTo()`, which is ultimately picked up by the node as `OracleRequest()` you can, but you have to specify it.
3. `encode_mwr` is just a placeholder for data that would need to be posted on-chain. You can read more about it. Most likely this will be the output of an `ethabiencode` task.

References:
[Migration Guide](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/migration-v1-v2/)
[ETH Tx job](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/task-types/eth-tx/)

Comment: Thanks Zak, appreciate the response. I have two quick follow ups. One, which interface/contract is an event OracleRequest called? I only saw oracleRequest as a function called in operatirInterface and I thought it had to be an event.     Second, when I do req.add(<key>), is the bytes data param what contains the CBOR data?

Comment: Hi @JamiePickett, the OracleReqeust event is emitted as part of the Oracle.sol and the Coordinator.sol contracts https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/search?l=Gerber+Image&q=event+OracleRequest, and yes, in the example you posted from the docs, the cborPayload bytes param contains the request data

Comment: Hey @HarryPapacharissiou, so as an update I moved back to v0.6, since in v0.8 and v0.7 I couldn't find the OracleRequest Event... I ran a local node and deployed my oracle on Kovan and we input the TOML, and our task list runs...up until the cborParse. The part that is supposed to have the CBOR passed (in docs the step is called cbor_parse) failed, and it seemed like that no data was passed? even though there should have been since we did multiple req.add(key,value) lines before calling sendChainlinkRequestTo...so maybe the TOML cborParse is no picking up correctly?

Comment: Hi @JamiePickett, can you post the whole JSON output of the job? or link to a text file containing it. I ran the example specified in the migration page ('Runlog with ETH ABI encoding', and I didn't have this issue https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/migration-v1-v2/

Comment: @HarryPapacharissou, it doesn’t let me post the whole TOML file in comments... I can send over discord PM

Answer (score 0):

Try using this TOML

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Get > Uint256-2"
contractAddress = "0xA74F1E1Bb6204B9397Dac33AE970E68F8aBC7651"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=http method=GET url="$(decode_cbor.get)"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="$(decode_cbor.path)" data="$(fetch)"]
    multiply     [type=multiply input="$(parse)" times=100]     
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data=<{ "value": $(multiply) }>]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data=<{"requestId": $(decode_log.requestId), "payment": $(decode_log.payment), "callbackAddress": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), "callbackFunctionId": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), "expiration": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), "data": $(encode_data)}>
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0xA74F1E1Bb6204B9397Dac33AE970E68F8aBC7651" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> multiply -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

And try use that in conjunction with this consumer contract https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://deploy-preview-427--dreamy-villani-0e9e5c.netlify.app/samples/APIRequests/ATestnetConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js